# In Solaris SecureRandom.setSeed("abc") is bypassed

Tags: security, random, cryptography

Hi I have the following snippet of code:

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG" , "SUN");
secureRandom.setSeed("seed");
keyGen.init(DEFAULT_KEY_LENGTH, secureRandom);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
byte[] encodedKey = secretKey.getEncoded();
```

the "encoded key" is giving me the same result everytime on platform window, AIX, linux. HP-Unix, but it is giving different result in solaris, it seems setSeed() is not working for Solaris or it is bypasssed,

Please help me, i am breaking my head on this since last two days.

Thanks
Shivam

Comment: Why would you pass a seed to a secure PRNG? In tests that might be useful (even that's doubtful), in production code it certainly isn't. If you want to derive random data from a short key, use a well defined stream cipher (e.g. AES-CTR).

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc on `SecureRandom.setSeed(long)` says:

> The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed.

`SecureRandom` does not work the same way as `java.util.Random` – the `Random` algorithm is standardized across all implementations, whereas no guarantees are made about the `SecureRandom` algorithm.

Also note that

> [...] any seed material passed to a SecureRandom object must be unpredictable.

which is not the case here. If your seed material is not unpredictable, the resulting random numbers likely won't be either, so there is no use for a cryptographically secure random number generator.

Comment: The guarantee crypt-strong PRNG provides is that you need a lot of previous samples to guess the next number produced.  The problem with predictable seeds is that an attacker can use previous observations to aid in an attack, thereby widening the window of vulnerability.  If the seed is completely predictable, then they can reliably guess.

Comment: BUt i dont understand one why i am able to get the same key with the same passphrase everytime i execute my code, on windows, linux and AIX, but only on solaris i am hitting this issue.

Comment: @user2131172 Because the SecureRandom algorithm is not standard. It just *happens* to be the same on all platforms you've tested except Solaris. The Solaris algorithm follows the specification too – nothing forbids the behavior you're experiencing. What I was trying to say with the last sentence in the answer is that you obviously don't need the cryptographically secure properties of SecureRandom in this case: go with the standardized Random instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare your keyGen as this way 
**keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES","SunJCE");**
you can get the same key on solaris.
all the other platforms use SunJCE as the default provider,but solaris uses SunPKCS11-Solaris as the default.